# JVM type representation on method area

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any reference which I could check on how Java developers decided to represent type information of a specific object? I know that the `Class` instance for a particular type is linked to that data structures and acts as an interface to it.

Comment: You could look at the bytecode...?

Comment: Jikes RVM is a good starting point for exploring VM internals.

Comment: Why don't you look at the byte code of [an actual JVM implementation](http://openjdk.java.net/)? As far as I remember from the little analyzing I did on the OpenJDK they call their *internall* class representation `klass`.

Comment: What sort of type information are you interested in?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I thought it was `jclass`

Comment: @Jivings: I might be wrong on that one, it's been a while.

Comment: I was simply wondering how the type information is stored for fields, methods etc. That is later on to be used by `Class` objects. I was intereseted in abstract terms what it's like - arrays, trees etc. rather than low-level bytecode stuff

Comment: @Bober02: actually what you're asking **is** pretty low-level. It *could* be any number of things, because the spec doesn't require one implementation or another. The **actual** implementation **is** the low-level stuff (it's actually *below* the bytecode level). So *either* you care about the **concrete** implementation or you don't.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry, I did not mean to be disrespectful. In this case I care about ONE, CONCRETE implementation detail -> these details might be abstracted, if you can

Comment: @Bober02: I wasn't under the impression that you were disrespectful in any way. I just wanted to tell you that what you're asking *is* a lot lower-level than you seem to think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is about how this information is encoded in a class file, it's described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html).

If you want to know how all this is represented in memory, your best bet is the source code of VM implementations.

Comment: I think this is about as close to an answer as this question is going to get.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a program, you can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to access a class's fields (or methods).

```
public void dumpFields(Class clz) {
    for (Field f : clz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(f.toString());
    }
}
```

If you're dealing with a .class file, you can decompile it using [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad).